# PHP Select random second value

Tags: php

I have a file called file.txt and inside I have this text:

```
Text 1
Vivamus arcu neque, ullamcorper vel eleifend id, euismod viverra nisi.

Text 2
Cras posuere neque vitae fringilla lobortis.

Text 2
Phasellus eu sapien sit amet diam eleifend ultricies a vitae tellus.

Text 3
Nulla at ipsum et quam euismod porttitor sit amet sed odio.
```

I select from this file 'Text 2' line and description under that line.

I want to select a random 'Text 2' line and its description not all of them. I tried to break that but it shows me only the first value of course and I tried to shuffle %trimmed but it didn't worked as I expected.

```
$trimmed = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$value = 2;

foreach ($trimmed as $line) {

    if ($line == "Text $value") {
        echo $line."<br>";
        echo current($trimmed);
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What creates the `file.txt`? Why not XML?

Comment: The file.txt will store some Quests for a game. Level 1 and the description of the quest.

Comment: You may use another format like JSon.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - why XML??   I'd have thought YAML or JSON would be a cleaner format for something like this. Or even just a simple INI file. XML seems like severe overkill for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might be bulky :

```
<?php

  function get_random_line($number, $file='file.txt'){

    $trimmed = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $string = "Text $number";

    $array = array();  
    foreach ($trimmed as $key => $line) {

      if($key % 2 == 0){
        $arr_key = $line;
        if(!array_key_exists($arr_key,$array)){
          $array[$arr_key]['total'] = 0;
        }
      }else{
        $array[$arr_key]['total']++;
        $array[$arr_key]['rows'][] = $line; 
      }         

    }
    if(key_exists($string,$array)){
      $key = array_rand($array[$string]['rows'],1);
      return $array[$string]['rows'][$key];
    }else
    {
      return 'Provide a Valid Key';
    }

  }


  echo '<pre>';
  print_r(get_random_line(3,'file.txt')); // Get Random Lines based on Label Value
  echo '</pre>';

?>
```